# Segregate tests to 'describe' and 'it' based on JSON object iteration using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a JSON file with below data.

```
[
  {    
    "routineCode": "StudentMapping",
    "routineId": "NIL",
    "routineClass": "NIL",
    "routineUpdate": "NIL",
    "routineMap": "Create-Role-Grade"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "createRole",
    "routineId": "791",
    "routineClass": "POCOD1",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Create-Role"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "createGrade",
    "routineId": "3094",
    "routineClass": "DWR145",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Create-Grade"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "StudentMapping",
    "routineId": "NIL",
    "routineClass": "NIL",
    "routineUpdate": "NIL",
    "routineMap": "Edit-Role-Grade"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "EditRole",
    "routineId": "791",
    "routineClass": "POCOD5",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Edit-Role"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "EditGrade",
    "routineId": "3094",
    "routineClass": "DWR298",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Edit-Grade"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "StudentMapping",
    "routineId": "NIL",
    "routineClass": "NIL",
    "routineUpdate": "NIL",
    "routineMap": "Delete-Role-Grade"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "DeleteRole",
    "routineId": "791",
    "routineClass": "POCOD5",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Delete-Role"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "DeleteGrade",
    "routineId": "3094",
    "routineClass": "DWR298",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Delete-Grade"
  } 
]
```

Now, I have wrote the code in cypress for reading this JSON file and entering data in application.

```
const jsonObjectRoute = require('../../fixtures/routeMap.json');
for(let route of jsonObjectRoute){
   let str_RoutineCode = route.routineCode;
   let str_RoutineId = route.routineId;
   let str_RoutineClass = route.routineClass;
   let str_RoutineUpdate = route.routineUpdate;

   it(str_RoutineCode, function() {
      cy.get('.RLNET_202').type(str_RoutineId);
      cy.get('.RLNET_CT_414').type(str_RoutineClass);
      cy.get('.RLNET_CT_414').type(str_RoutineUpdate );
   });
}
```

From the JSON Object, there is a routine code - 'StudentMapping' appearing 3 times. This has no data to be entered in application and it's rather a dummy test that gets executed. I want that alone to go inside 'describe' each time it appears in the iteration.

So that first time for describe - 'StudentMapping', the tests 'createRole' and 'createGrade' gets executed.
2nd time for 'StudentMapping', the tests 'EditRole' and 'EditGrade' gets executed.
3rd time for 'StudentMapping', the tests 'DeleteRole' and 'DeleteGrade' gets executed.

Could someone please help me to achieve this?

Comment: How do you want "describe"? You have `it(RoutineCode,` but what title for describe, please clarify.

Comment: Both describe and it will be he value for routineCode. describe(str_RoutineCode, function() {...}.  The title for the describe should be 'StudentMapping' for the 3 iterations. Under each iteration, the title of the tests varies as said above.

Comment: This seems like another layer of complexity for maintenance. Is your JSON data being used across different test files with different test steps themselves?

Comment: The JSON data file is used in only a single test file.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want to "group" the list?

```js
let current = []
const groups = jsonObjectRoute.reduce((acc, jor) => {
  if (jor.routineCode = 'StudentMapping') {
    if (current.length) { 
      acc.push(current)
    }
    current = []
  } else {
    current.push(jor)
  }
  return acc
}, [])
groups.push(current)

// now groups is [
//   [{createRole...}, {createGrade...}], 
//   [{EditRole...},   {EditGrade...}],
//   ... and so on
// ]

for (let group of groups) {
  for (let route of group) {
    ...
```

---

If you can change the fixture structure, make it so

```js
[
  {    
    "routineMap": "Create-Role-Grade",
    "tests": [
      {    
        "routineCode": "createRole",
        ...
      },
      {    
        "routineCode": "createGrade",
        ...
      },
    ]
  },
  {    
    "routineMap": "Edit-Role-Grade",
    "tests": [
      {    
        "routineCode": "EditRole",
        ...
      },
      {    
        "routineCode": "EditGrade",
        ...
      },
    ]
  },
  {    
    "routineMap": "Delete-Role-Grade"
    "tests": [
      {    
        "routineCode": "DeleteRole",
        ...
      },
      {    
        "routineCode": "DeleteGrade",
        ...
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

It doesn't really make sense to carry extra properties which don't do anything.

Now your file has two arrays built in, you can remove the reducer

```js
// Spec

const jsonObjectRoute = require('../../fixtures/routeMap.json')
for (let group of jsonObjectRoute) {
  describe(`Tesing ${group.routineMap`, () => {
    for (let route of group) {
      it(`Tesing ${route.routineMap`, function() {
        cy.get('.RLNET_202').type(route.routineId);
        cy.get('.RLNET_CT_414').type(route.routineClass);
        cy.get('.RLNET_CT_414').type(route.routineUpdate);
      });
```

Comment: for(let group of groups) {                           
    describe(str_RoutineCode, function() {
        for(let autoStep of group) {
   let str_RoutineCode = route.routineCode;
   let str_RoutineId = route.routineId;
   let str_RoutineClass = route.routineClass;
   let str_RoutineUpdate = route.routineUpdate;
   
   it(str_RoutineCode, function() {
    cy.get('.RLNET_202').type(str_RoutineId);
    cy.get('.RLNET_CT_414').type(str_RoutineClass);
    cy.get('.RLNET_CT_414').type(str_RoutineUpdate );
   })
  }
 })
}

Comment: Hi, the above code as per your suggestion missing 2 points. The first one, I need to have a describe statement with title as routine code as like 'it'. The title of describe would be 'StudentMapping' for each iteration of the outer for loop. The second issue, the inner for loop iterates till 'EditGrade' alone. The last iteration 'DeleteRole' and 'DeleteGrade' is missing.

Comment: Adding the describe is trivial, it is always `describe('StudentMapping', () => {...` according to your comment above.

Comment: Easy to fix, just push the last group after the reducer.

Comment: As you suggested, pushed the last group after the reducer. Able to get all tests. After running the script in test runner, I am seeing 'StudentMapping' 4 times in the results. The first when I expand in results, it's empty. The 2nd one has 'CreateRole', 'CreateGrade', 3rd one has 'EditRole', 'EditGrade', and 4th one has 'DeleteRole', 'DeleteGrade'. There should be only 3 describe statements with 'StudentMapping' instead of 4. The first emtpy one in results not required. Why this is occuring?

Comment: And, I have included one more attribute to the JSON object 'routineMap'. Instead of routineCode as 'StudentMapping', is it possible to bring the values of routineMap for the 3 describe statements as it will vary.

Comment: I guess the describe should be between the two `for (let...)` statements - should give you one  for each group.

Comment: If you can change the structure of `routeMap.json`, that will save some headaches.

Comment: If I move describe as you suggested, then each test comes within a describe and this is not what I need. The tests 'createRole' and 'createGrade' should be within the 1st describe. The tests 'editRole' and 'editGrade' should be within the 2nd describe and so on. That's the reason we did this grouping. The code mentioned above provides the way I want but the results provides me an empty describe which is not required. The output should contain only 3 describe statements but it has 4. The first one is empty and the remaining 3 describe are as expected. How to get rid of the first empty one?

Comment: Yeah, I know this would be more complicate if we change the json but I need either the routineCode or routineMap as the title of the describe. If I achieve this, then this will be a whole. Please let me now, is this is possible to achieve? Changing the fixture structure would affect other teams referring to this JSON file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241771/discussion-between-saran-and-fody).